# Why does Javascript string replace reverse the word order for right to left languages?

Tags: javascript, internationalization

I'm curious as to why the following placeholder replacement for a right to left language (these are random Arabic characters) causes the formatted string to reverse all the words.

```
'{0} تكنولوجيا'.replace('{0}', 'هلهل')
=> "هلهل تكنولوجيا"
```

This behavior was observed in the latest Chrome, FF, and Safari. It keeps the word order the same in Node.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't. `replace` does exactly what you asked it to do: Replaces the first three letters of that string with `هلهل`; I'm going to make it *four* rather than three so the original and the replacement are the same length (makes it easier to see what's going on):

```js
var before = '{00} تكنولوجيا';
var rep = 'هلهل';
var after = before.replace('{00}', rep);
console.log("before", before.split("").map(toCharCode).join(", "));
console.log("rep   ", rep.split("").map(toCharCode).join(", "));
console.log("after ", after.split("").map(toCharCode).join(", "));

function toCharCode(c) {
  var hex = c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16);
  hex = "0000".substr(hex.length - 4) + hex;
  return "U-" + hex;
}
```

Output:

```
before U-007b, U-0030, U-0030, U-007d, U-0020, U-062a, U-0643, U-0646, U-0648, U-0644, U-0648, U-062c, U-064a, U-0627
rep    U-0647, U-0644, U-0647, U-0644
after  U-0647, U-0644, U-0647, U-0644, U-0020, U-062a, U-0643, U-0646, U-0648, U-0644, U-0648, U-062c, U-064a, U-0627
```

Note that the replacement sequence (U-0647, U-0644, U-0647, U-0644) is now at the beginning of the string.

What you're seeing is the way the string is **displayed**. Because contiguous spans of RTL characters are displayed right-to-left, and you now have a single span of RTL which is shown in that way: The replacement is at the beginning (the far right) and the text continues to the left. Before, you had a mis of LTR and RTL, which was shown with the LTR (shown from left to right) followed by the RTL (shown from right to left).